# Arm Assembly & C++

Tags: c++, architecture, arm

Hello I am reading a book on ARM architecture. (I am a noob)
I was reading about the cpu's register file.

When I create a variable in c++ is this the data that is sent to the register file through the bus RM & then sent to the ALU in the cpu? example: (int a = 1 + 1;)

And is the address register what gives me back the memory address through the address bus? (example: &a)

The book doesn't mention c++ but I am just wondering.

I just want to see if I am understanding this right. Thanks for any answers.

Comment: Registers aren't files.  They are discrete, fixed size data storage units inside the CPU.  In order to process data, the data must first be loaded into a register.

Comment: @Wug the _register file_ is the set of general purpose registers. This is a common expression in computer architecture and has nothing to with the files of the operating system.

Comment: if you're interested, you can tell your compiler to generate a combined C++/asm list file. That way you can see what each C++ statement is converted too.

Answer (score 3):

It is probably not a good idea to try to associate C++ directly with hardware like register files or address buses. It makes more sense to insert assembly language as intermediate level. So think how your C++ is translated into assembly code and *then* how that assembly code controls the hardware. Your book on ARM will teach you the connection between assembly and hardware. To understand the relation between C++ and assembly it is probably best to look at some compiler output.

You can use compiler options to examine the assembly output of your C++ compiler. For example with g++:

$ cat -n test.cc

```
 1  int a;
 2  
 3  void f() {
 4      a = a + 1;
 5  }
```

$ arm-elf-c++-4.6 -O2 -c -g -Wa,-ahl=test.s test.cc

$ less +/4:test.cc test.s

```
  [...]
   4:test.cc       ****         a = a + 1;
  16                            .loc 1 5 0
  17 0000 0C309FE5              ldr     r3, .L2
  18 0004 002093E5              ldr     r2, [r3, #0]
  19 0008 012082E2              add     r2, r2, #1
  20 000c 002083E5              str     r2, [r3, #0]
  [...]
```

You can see that the address of *a* (called `.L2`) is moved to register `r3` in line 17, then in line 18 *a* is retrieved from memory and incremented in line 19 and finally in line 20 stored again into main memory.

Answer (score 1):

The compiler may optimize your code by putting variables' contents into registers (as registers are faster than RAM), but in general variables are stored in RAM, on the stack, and `&variable` gives the (virtual) address of the variable in the RAM. (the 'address register' you mentioned is unrelated to this -- giving the 'address of a processor register' doesn't make sense, only RAM bytes have addresses.)

Answer (score 1):

`int a = 1 + 1;` will just load variable `a` with 2. But indeed, addresses of variables are the real addresses in memory, so the address that goes to the address bus.

I have to add that this is just the case if `a` was declared globally. As local variables will live on stack and the address will be a temporary stack location.

Comment: Not really; they're rather virtual addresses the OS assigns to the process.

Comment: Oh you're talking about an OS? I was talking about programming on a bare-metal ARM :)

Comment: I assumed there's an OS - no great changes, though.

Answer (score 1):

In order to process data, the data must first be loaded into a register.  When you do arithmetic, you load values into a register, and an instruction causes the cpu to apply some operation to one or more registers.  Arithmetic ones typically take 2 registers as input and store the value in a third.  The CPU marshals the ALU through performing the calculation.  This value may be stored back into memory immediately, but it may not, at the compilers discretion.  The addressof operation is mostly handled by the compiler, since it knows the layout in memory of the program, but the program doesn't.

Comment: Are there any books that show the relationship between High level languages and low level cpu activity.

Comment: Sure there are.  I don't know any off the top of my head.  :S However, I can tell you that you aren't supposed to worry about that.  When you're using a language like java, you aren't supposed to think about how the cpu is actually doing the things you tell it to.  That's why we use high level languages: so we don't have to care.  If you're using a language like C or C++, the compiler does have an option to compile to assembly language.  I believe it's the -S flag on GCC.

Comment: Thanks.. I just have a fascination to know low and high level code. Maybe I will make me a better programmer. one more question.. What do I use on windows to write arm assembly? or do I have to buy an Arm pc?

Comment: You'd want an ARM emulator.  Again, no idea what to look for.  I bet wikipedia has a list of them though.